# Can't call javascript function in ASP.NET cs page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have below JavaScript function in my aspx page:

```
<script>
    function ShowMessage() {
        alert("Hello World");
    }
</script>
```

I want to use this function in my cs page on button click event:

```
<asp:Button ID="MyButton" runat="server" Text="Click Here" OnClick="MyButton_Click" />
```

Now this code works fine:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "alert('Hello World');", true);
```

But this code dose not work:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myScript", "ShowMessage();", true);
```

What's wrong in my code? What's the possible reason?

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?  Please check the source html in browser to check if the file has ShowMessage function.

Comment: I checked the page source and i found my function in page

Comment: Can you please update the question with the page source.

Comment: Use the browser's dev-tools to see the javascript console. Any errors mentioned there?

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose your `ShowMessage()` function to a scope that your DOM has access to.

You can try:

```
window.ShowMessage = function() {
  alert("Hello World");
}
```

Another option is to move your `<script></script>` containing your function *ABOVE* the DOM element that needs it:

```
<script>
  function Foo() {
    alert('Bar');
  }

</script>

<button onclick="Foo()"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use onclientclick

```
<asp:Button ID="MyButton" runat="server" Text="Click Here" onclientclick="ShowMessage()" />
```

Comment: The OP might *want* a server-side event, to execute some server code before that message shows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    $('#idOfButton').click(
        function() {
            alert("Hello World"); 
        }
    );
</script>
```

**Note:** use JQuery for this code and paste this on the end of your HTML page.

Hope this will help

Comment: The OP might *want* a server-side event, to execute some server code before that message shows.